# What's the name of this theorem(or conjecture) on contracting maps?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

I'm considering the following assertion and I believe it is correct: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $a,b\in X$ and $d(a,b)=1$, then there exists a contracting map $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$. If my memory is correct, it is a theorem, does anybody know the name of it?

Comment: This is too trivial to be a "named" theorem.  Just take $f(x) = \min(1, d(a,x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the comments, this is in fact a true statement, probably too easy to be named. Another suitable function is given by $$f(x)=\frac{d(a,x)}{d(a,x)+d(b,x)},$$ since $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \frac{1}{d(a,x)+d(b,x)} |d(a,x)-d(a,y)| \le d(x,y).$$

This has the nice additional property that $f(x)=0$ implies $x=a$ and $f(x)=1$ implies $x=b$.